# SetContentView without displaying the screen (yet)?

Tags: android

Is there a way in an Android Activity to do a *setContentView()*, so that I can have Android compute the layout, and so I can successfully get Views in it via *findViewByID()*, **but not yet display it**?

This would be in an app with a main activity and some subordinate activities and the one I want to start but not display would be one of the subordinate activities. (in other words the main view would already be filling up the screen, so it would be sufficient to simply keep the new one hidden at the bottom of the view hierarchy).  The activity would be started with a "standard" launch mode.

If there's a way to do it by keeping it at the bottom of the View hierarchy, how would I force it to the top when I do want to display it?

NOTE: This app already exists - it's a large, complex industrial app with 14 Activities, written for Android 2.35 and 2.36, so re-architecting it to use Fragments instead of Activities would be impractical.  I just want to modify one Activity to not display, or to just display at the bottom of the View hierarchy so it's not visible.

Comment: Set the `visibility` to `GONE`?

Comment: What are "subordinate activities"?

Comment: Perhaps move from Activity layouts to Fragments?

Comment: @CommonsWare - by "subordinate" I mean Activities launched from the main Activity.   When you start the app you're on the main screen, from there you can go to other screens, each of which is its own Activity; when you leave those you're back on the main screen.   What would be a better term than "subordinate" for those?

Comment: "What would be a better term than "subordinate" for those?" -- I'd use "other". "Fragments were introduced in Android 3.0 so are not an option)" -- yes, they are. A backport of fragments has been in the Android Support package for three years.

Comment: @Niek Haarman Visibility is a property of a View.   So how I would I set it to GONE without first displaying it?   As I explained in my Question, I want to call onCreate and do the layout, etc, but I don't want to display it. (I want to main screen to remain visible) If I set it to GONE in the XML would it what do I get when I call setContentView?

Comment: @CommonsWare - what is a "backport"?

Comment: @user316117: "Backport" is the term used for taking code designed to run on newer environments and adjusting it to be usable on older environments. In Android, the term is usually used for taking some of Google's source code for something designed for, say, API Level 11+ devices, and creating a version can than be used on older devices as well (e.g., API Level 7+).

Comment: @CommonsWare As I read up on Fragments it looks like switching from an Activity based architecture to a Fragments based one would be huge undertaking for an existing, large complex app as this one.  I think I could achieve my goal by just forcing it to the bottom of the View hierarchy, **if** there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This would be in an app with a main activity and some subordinate activities and the one I want to start but not display would be one of the subordinate activities

That is not possible. Or, more accurately, you are welcome to start that activity and not populate its UI, but it will still take over the screen, and so the user will be presented with a blank screen, which is not especially useful.

> in other words the main view would already be filling up the screen, so it would be sufficient to simply keep the new one hidden at the bottom of the view hierarchy

Each activity has its own view hierarchy. A "subordinate activity" cannot and will not be at the top, bottom, or anywhere else with respect to some other activity's view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Im quite new to Android but I think that this can bea easily done using fragments. One fragment will be the one that will be currently shown and the other will be overrlayed with a hiden parent view for an example. When you need to show the other fragment just set the layout to visible.

Hope it works, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using Fragments *which I suggest you to use them* you can use `LayoutInflater` to inflate whatever layout you like and change between them using `setContentView` repeatedly.

```
    View layout1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(/*your first layout */ R.layout.activity_layout_1, getWindow().getDecorView());
    //here you can use findViewByID like this
    View someViewInLayout1 = layout1.findViewByID(R.id.some_view);
    //... get fields for all others views you need here in layout1
    //than you inflate your other layout
    View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(/*your second layout */ R.layout.activity_layout_2, getWindow().getDecorView());
    //... do the same for layout2
```

Now you can call `setContentView` whenever you want to change between layouts.

```
setContentView(layout1 /*or layout2*/);
```

Comment: These are not separate layouts, they are whole separate Activities, as I explained in my question.   I'd like to stick as closely as possible to the existing architecture but I just don't want the Activity's screen to be visible when I setContentView().  I want to make it visible later.